# Making a node-fetch POST request with file as payload

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, fetch

first time poster, excited to have a community to collaborate with here!

So here's my situation. I'm using Node to put together an automation for my company's compliance - taking reports from our MDM server and posting them to our compliance platform (Tugboat Logic). The idea is to have it deployed on a recurring basis via AWS Lambda. The basic logic is this: getToken fetches an auth token which is then passed to getReports. getReports loops through an array of endpoints to get reports from the MDM and then passes those along to fileReport - which then posts that data to the endpoint.

The problem is that the final endpoint needs a file as the payload (sample POST request below). I managed to get the whole fetch chain working by using fs writeFile/readFile (and a delay), and while that worked, it doesn't translate well into a Lambda environment. Ideally, I want to just take the payload from getReports (which comes through as JSON but can also be accepted as text) and push it straight to the endpoint. Any help on how I could clean up this code would be appreciated!

Here's the bit giving me the most trouble (from the last file)

`` form.append('file', x, `${reportsArray[i].name}.json`); ``

```
// Sample post request for final endpoint
curl -v --user <provided-username>:<given-password> \
 -H "X-API-KEY: <given-x-api-key>" \
 -F "collected=<date-of-evidence>" -F "file=@<local_filename_csv>;type=text/csv" \
 <given-collector-url>
```

```
//getReports.js accepts a token from an earlier function and takes fileReport as the cb
function getReports(token, cb) {
    const headers = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        redirect: 'follow'
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < reportsArray.length; i++) {
        fetch(reportsArray[i].source, headers)
        .then(res => res.json())
        // writeFile leftover from successful deploy
        /*.then(data => fs.writeFile(`./reports/${reportsArray[i].name}.json`, data, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        }))*/
        .then(res => cb(i, res))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
};
```

```
//fileReport.js - i identifies the right endpoint from the imported array and sets filename. x is the JSON payload passed down from getReports
function fileReport(i, x) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('collected', getTimestamp());
    form.append('file', x, `${reportsArray[i].name}.json`);
    fetch(`${reportsArray[i].dest}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-API-KEY': `${process.env.TUGBOAT_X_API_KEY}`,
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${process.env.TUGBOAT_USERNAME}:${process.env.TUGBOAT_PASSWORD}`)
        },
        body: form
    });
};
```

Comment: Just to be clear here, there's no such thing as a file as a payload.  A payload is a payload.  You can set a header such as `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.txt"` which tells the recipient that the data "may" be treated as a file with this name, but that's entirely up to the recipient what they do with it.  If you want multiple, separate payloads, then you would form it into some sort of multipart MIME format and the recipient would have to know how to parse that.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here.  Pushing content from one source to a destination without buffer it all is usually done by piping the incoming stream to an output stream either using `.pipe()` or `pipeline()`, both of which are stream functions.  Other than that, I don't understand what you're asking to know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing your file correctly to `formData`

Here's pseudo code that demonstrates what works:

```js
const file = fs.createReadStream("/path/to/file");
const url = "https://your.com/upload";
const fields = {}; // additional fields
const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries({ ...fields, file }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  formData.append(key, value);
});
// built-in node fetch()
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
}).then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Upload failed ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  console.log("file uploaded");
});
```

**Bonus:**

If you need to do this in the browser, you just need to swap out the `file` to use the user-selected file.

Here's how.

Instead of:

```
const file = fs.createReadStream("/path/to/file");
```

have a form element like this:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" onChange={(e) => documentGetLocalFile(e)} />
```

and a handler like this:

```
var file;
documentGetLocalFile(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    file = event.target.files[0];
  }
}
```

Then just make sure your `formData` uses this `file` in place of the `fs.createReadStream()` file you removed above.